# Read data from remote hive on spark over JDBC returns empty result

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, jdbc, hive

I need to execute hive queries on remote hive server from spark, but for some reasons i receive only column names(without data).
Data available in table, i checked it via HUE and java jdbc connection.

Here is my code example:

```
val test = spark.read
    .option("url", "jdbc:hive2://remote.hive.server:10000/work_base")
    .option("user", "user")
    .option("password", "password")
    .option("dbtable", "some_table_with_data")
    .option("driver", "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")
    .format("jdbc")
    .load()
test.show()
```

Output:

```
+-------+
|dst.col|
+-------+
+-------+
```

I know that data vailable on this table.

Scala version: 2.11
Spark version: 2.1.0, i also tried 2.1.1
Hive version: CDH 5.7 Hive 1.1.1, on HDP i have same story
Hive JDBC version: 1.1.1 i also tried later versions

But this problem available on Hive with later versions, too.
Could you help me with this issue, because i didn't find anything in mail group answers and StackOverflow.
Maybe you know how i can execute hive queries from spark to remote servers?

Answer (score 2):

Paul Staab replied on this issue in Spark jira.
Here is solution:

1. Create an Hive Dialect which uses the correct quotes for escaping the column names:

   ```
   object HiveDialect extends JdbcDialect {

       override def canHandle(url: String): Boolean = url.startsWith("jdbc:hive2")

       override def quoteIdentifier(colName: String): String = s"`$colName`"
   }
   ```
2. Register it before making the call with spark.read.jdbc

   ```
   JdbcDialects.registerDialect(HiveDialect)
   ```
3. Execute spark.read.jdbc with fetchsize option

   ```
   spark.read.jdbc("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default","test1",properties={"driver": "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver", "fetchsize": "10"}).show()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should add this into your options:

```
 .option("fetchsize", "10")
```

Comment: It returns 
`
+-----+
|t.col|
+-----+
|t.col|
+-----+
`
but i need data.

Comment: I have the same problem too, the number of lines is correct, but the value is always the column name. I am still trying to solve

Comment: I created bug on Spark. Here's link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21063

Let me know if you find something.