# Spark returning empty result from when querying remote hive

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, hive

Spark returning empty result from when querying remote hive
spark tried from 2.1.1   to spark spark 2. 3. 2

Code snippet is:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val dataframe_mysql = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:hive2://10.0.0.28:10000/default").option("driver", "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver").option("dbtable", "load1").load()
dataframe_mysql.show()
```

queries reached in hive are

```
SELECT * FROM load1 WHERE 1=0
```

and on dataframe_mysql.show()

```
 SELECT "load1.data_id","load1.id","load1.gender","load1.totcount","load1.fname" FROM load1
```

result am getting

```
scala> dataframe_mysql.show()
+--------+-----------+------------+--------------+-------------+                
|load1.id|load1.fname|load1.gender|load1.totcount|load1.data_id|
+--------+-----------+------------+--------------+-------------+
+--------+-----------+------------+--------------+-------------+
```

thanks in advance

Comment: tried from spark 2.1.1 to 2.3.2
    due to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21063

Comment: related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434304/read-data-from-remote-hive-on-spark-over-jd    bc-returns-empty-result    answer also not working

Answer (score 0):

till sark 3.3.0 (spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop2) have no fix

some workaround available  (open terminal enter **spark-shell**)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.{JdbcDialect, JdbcDialects}

class HiveDialect extends JdbcDialect{
  override def canHandle(url: String): Boolean = 
    url.startsWith("jdbc:hive2")
  

  override def quoteIdentifier(colName: String): String = {
    if(colName.contains(".")){
      var colName1 = colName.substring(colName.indexOf(".") + 1)
      return s"`$colName1`"
    }
    s"`$colName`"
  }
}
JdbcDialects.registerDialect(new HiveDialect)


import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val dataframe_mysql = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:hive2://10.0.0.28:10000/default").option("driver", "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver").option("dbtable", "load1").load()

dataframe_mysql.show()
```

[image]